# Camera Preview Frames interlaced with Media playback Error

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-camera

I took the code from grafika for [Double Decoder](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/DoubleDecodeActivity.java) and changed it so that one textureview is outputting from mediaplayer and the other textureview outputting the camera preview. It would be working fine except that in the textureview with the media player output will get frames of the camera preview interlaced. It's really funky behavior and I am not doing anything dynamic to reconfigure the output viewport.

Both Textureviews & SurfaceTextures are separated and are independently assigned to their respective output -> mediaplayer output and camera preview output:

> mediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);
>
> camera.setPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);

Running the mediaPlayer code and camera code on a separate threads does not help. It seems like the SurfaceTexture frame buffers are being somehow being shared and frames are being dropped or interfering with each other? Could this be be a performance issue? Even when the original example of the code was to be able to decode movies in parallel?

Comment: Maybe the SurfaceTextures under the TextureViews are being set up with the same texture name?  You can't cross-up the BufferQueue producer/consumer, but you could have multiple writers to the same GLES texture.  Does anything change if you change the order in which things are configured (or switch which thing appears in which view)?

Comment: Hey fadden - thanks for the suggestion. I got the impression that I was using the same SurfaceTexture as well; however, I have two instances of TextureView which is confusing because they shouldn't create the same SurfaceTexture?

Comment: So, I dug into the android code a little bit. Put breakpoints onSurfaceTextureAvailable for both TextureViews. The textureName for each SurfaceTexture is different (eg. 1972614224 & 1996512936). So the textureid doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: Is only one TextureView showing interlaced images, or both? Or maybe the second is blank?

Comment: Only one is actually showing interlaced - the one playing the video (where some of the camera frames are showing up). I suspect that the issue may be a result of the blitter? I think that the camera is creating more frames per seconds which is causing some of those frames to be sent over? My GL knowledge is pretty limited so sorry if I sound ignorant.

Comment: It is possible that this is HW  / product specific. Your device's platform might use the same buffer for media playback and camera recording thus resulting in funky frames. You can verify this by running your app on a newer device / platform.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I am having exactly the same problem... I'm having this problem in an LG G2, I' trying to achieve something similar to Instagram's gallery, the funny thing is that in the Instagram app I don't see this happen, so there must be a solution...